# Firebase function only deployment issue with node_modules

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, node-modules

Having I'm following a reddit clone walkthrough and have encountered a problem when trying to execute this line in the terminal:

```
reddit-clone git:(main) ✗ firebase deploy --only functions
```

The final error message reads as:

```
Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 2
```

I'm trying to deploy a single function to my projects firebase account.

There seems to be an issue with the node modules? Below is the terminals output with the consequent errors.

```
➜  reddit-clone git:(main) ✗ firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'reddit-clone-####'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> build
> tsc

../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3135:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'.

3135         type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = C extends React.MemoExoticComponent<infer T> | React.LazyExoticComponent<infer T>
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../../../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3135:14
    3135         type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = C extends React.MemoExoticComponent<infer T> | React.LazyExoticComponent<infer T>
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'LibraryManagedAttributes' was also declared here.

../../../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3135:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'.

3135         type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = C extends React.MemoExoticComponent<infer T> | React.LazyExoticComponent<infer T>
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3135:14
    3135         type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = C extends React.MemoExoticComponent<infer T> | React.LazyExoticComponent<infer T>
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'LibraryManagedAttributes' was also declared here.

../../../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3152:13 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'audio' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AudioHTMLAttributes<HTMLAudioElement>, HTMLAudioElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<AudioHTMLAttributes<HTMLAudioElement>, HTMLAudioElement>'.

3152             audio: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.AudioHTMLAttributes<HTMLAudioElement>, HTMLAudioElement>;
                 ~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3152:13
    3152             audio: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.AudioHTMLAttributes<HTMLAudioElement>, HTMLAudioElement>;
                     ~~~~~
    'audio' was also declared here.

../../../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3200:13 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'input' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.

3200             input: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>;
                 ~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3200:13
    3200             input: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>;
                     ~~~~~
    'input' was also declared here.

../../../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3207:13 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'link' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<LinkHTMLAttributes<HTMLLinkElement>, HTMLLinkElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<LinkHTMLAttributes<HTMLLinkElement>, HTMLLinkElement>'.

3207             link: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.LinkHTMLAttributes<HTMLLinkElement>, HTMLLinkElement>;
                 ~~~~

  ../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3207:13
    3207             link: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.LinkHTMLAttributes<HTMLLinkElement>, HTMLLinkElement>;
                     ~~~~
    'link' was also declared here.

../../../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3235:13 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'script' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ScriptHTMLAttributes<HTMLScriptElement>, HTMLScriptElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ScriptHTMLAttributes<HTMLScriptElement>, HTMLScriptElement>'.

3235             script: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ScriptHTMLAttributes<HTMLScriptElement>, HTMLScriptElement>;
                 ~~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3235:13
    3235             script: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ScriptHTMLAttributes<HTMLScriptElement>, HTMLScriptElement>;
                     ~~~~~~
    'script' was also declared here.

../../../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3261:13 - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'video' must be of type 'DetailedHTMLProps<VideoHTMLAttributes<HTMLVideoElement>, HTMLVideoElement>', but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps<VideoHTMLAttributes<HTMLVideoElement>, HTMLVideoElement>'.

3261             video: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.VideoHTMLAttributes<HTMLVideoElement>, HTMLVideoElement>;
                 ~~~~~

  ../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3261:13
    3261             video: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.VideoHTMLAttributes<HTMLVideoElement>, HTMLVideoElement>;
                     ~~~~~
    'video' was also declared here.


Found 7 errors in 2 files.

Errors  Files
     1  ../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3135
     6  ../../../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3135

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 2
```

[image: Folder structure & the functions index.tsx file]

As far as I can tell, I've made some sort of mistake with setting up the project and packages? I tried a completed reinstall of npm but this didn't work. I can't work out why this simple task is catching errors in the node modules?

I've also made sure that all packages are up-to-date.

I've triple checked that firebase as been installed, I'm logged into my firebase account within the terminal and able to list available projects etc.

firebase.json file:

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Even a standard firebase deployment produces the same problem.

Also, node_modules is excluded in tsconfig/gitignore files.

A little point in the right direction would be appreciated!

Namaste

**UPDATE**
So I've managed to deploy the function, but there is an error:

[image: firebase function error]

This is what the console is now producing after running the "firebase deploy --only functions script"

````
```
    ➜  reddit-clone git:(main) ✗ firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'reddit-clone-####'...

i  deploying functions
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase reddit-clone for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged ########/redditClone/reddit-clone/functions (34.78 KB) for uploading
i  functions: Skipping the deploy of unchanged functions with experimental support for skipdeployingnoopfunctions
✔  functions[reddit-clone:createUserDocument(us-central1)] Skipped (No changes detected)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

✔  Deploy complete!

Project Console: #####
````

Why am I getting the "function deployment failed. Please try again" error?

What should I be looking?

Help appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to remove `node_modues` and `package-lock.json` file and reinstall libraries?

Comment: Yes thanks. I've tried this with both the main node_modules and package-lock.json files and the ones in the functions folder. With no luck.

Comment: Have you tried to install the exact same versions of the used libraries? Because those errors remind me of some kind of breaking change problems

Comment: Have u been able to find a solution to this?

Comment: I am encountering a very similar issue and gone through similar remedial steps as well. Super frustrating as this seems like it should be straight forward as its fresh after firebase init and selecting the functions options. I have also excluded node_modules. It seems to be picking up an issue in the node_modules of my higher level folder as that has React in it as well which the functions one does not. Seems like a typescript issue. Have you had any luck with this? Thanks.